# C# condense redundant code in class with INotifyPropertyChange

Tags: c#, class, inotifypropertychanged

I've been reading a few articles the past few days on inheriting classes and creating base classes, which i often do in tools I've written. However I specifically was looking into ways to reduce the redundant code often written in my classes which contain INotifyPropertyChange. Normally my classes look something like this, inheriting the base class of NotifyBase. However I've seen here a there in various scripts people moving some of the Get and Set code into the base class. I wanted to know what things to look out for when doing this? is this bad practice or good practice? Does the example I provided written correctly to do so?

One benefit being the Get and Set are much simpler in the classes which inherit NotifyBase in the new setup.

**Current Setup Example**

*FileItem Class*

```
using System.IO;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class FileItem : NotifyBase
    {
        private string _fullPath;
        public string FullPath
        {
            get { return this._fullPath; }
            set
            {
                this._fullPath = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("FullPath");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Base Class '*NotifyBase*'

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class NotifyBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Possible New Setup**

*FileItem Class*

```
using System.IO;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class FileItem : NotifyBase
    {
        public string FullPath
        {
            get { return Get<string>(); }
            set { Set(value); }
        }
    }
}
```

Base Class '*NotifyBase*'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Varo.Helper
{
    public class NotifyBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        private readonly Dictionary<string, object> _propertyValues;

        protected NotifyBase()
        {
           _propertyValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        }

        protected void Set<T>(T value, [CallerMemberName] string name = "")
        {
           if (_propertyValues.ContainsKey(name))
           {

               _propertyValues[name] = value;
               NotifyPropertyChanged(name);

           }
           else
           {
               _propertyValues.Add(name, value);
               NotifyPropertyChanged(name);
           }
        }

        protected T Get<T>([CallerMemberName] string name = "")
        {
           if (_propertyValues.ContainsKey(name))
           {
               return (T)_propertyValues[name];
           }
           return default(T);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you seen some of the alternative, existing solutions? This is a frequent problem and has been solved elsewhere many times. Base classes aren't ideal for this, as they can impact your class hierarchy quite drastically. (I prefer the [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) extension for ease of use and lack of impact on existing code, but your mileage may vary...)

Comment: awesome, thank you Dan. Fody will work out just perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [PropertyChanged.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) NuGet

Weaves .NET assembly at compile time so properties declared as

```
 public int Property { get; set; }
```

Gets compiled as

```
 private int property;
 public int Property 
 {
      get 
      {
        return property;
      }
      set
      {
        if(property != value)
        {
             property = value;
             if (this.PropertyChanged!= null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Property");
        }
      }
 }
```